# How do you use respondsToSelector & performSelector in PyObjc

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I'm converting a Objective-C program to PyObjC and lack experience in both.

Here is the Objective-C portion

```
WebPreferences *p = [webview preferences];
if([p respondsToSelector:@selector(setWebGLEnabled:)]){
[p performSelector:@selector(setWebGLEnabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
}
```

This is basically an undocumented method (yes I know I can't submit to app store) to enable WebGL in the WebView

I can't figure out how to translate this portion to PyObjC

Comment: Is this at all useful? http://lethain.com/how-to-use-selectors-in-pyobjc/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use performSelector, just call the method:

```
p = webview.preferences()
p.setWebGLEnabled_(True)
```

This works because PyObjC doesn't look at header files but at the Objective-C runtime to find out which methods are present.

Comment: Doesn't this still throw a Cocoa exception if `setWebGLEnabled_` doesn't exist on `p`?

Comment: It does. You can avoid that by using “hasattr”.

Comment: I am curious then, what makes you prefer the Python version of "Does this method exist? Then call it." over Cocoa's here?

Comment: I prefer the Python version because that gives (IMHO) cleaner code.

Comment: Fair enough. Python is, probably without exception, more satisfactory in the "elegance" department than ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

One of the magic bits of the bridge. You can just use the selector's string -- the method name (with colons, not underscores):

```
>>> from AppKit import *
>>> s = NSString.stringWithString_("Lemon curry?")
>>> s.respondsToSelector_("length")
True
>>> s.respondsToSelector_("count")
False
>>> s.respondsToSelector_("writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:")
True
>>> s.performSelector_("lowercaseString")
u'lemon curry?'
```